# Firebase downloads same data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, viewdidappear

I use firebase in swift, I call the listener in viewDidAppear: and as it is written in the docs it should't download the same data again but now every time the view appears the same data will be displayed.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    getData()
    self.messagesRef.keepSynced(true)
}
func getData(){
    messagesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (mesData: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

        let messageDict = mesData.value as! NSDictionary

        let key = mesData.key

        self.likedRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("likedMessages/\(currentUser.uid)/\(key)")

        self.likedRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (likedFd: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            if likedFd.value is NSNull{
                let liked = false
                let message = Message(message: messageDict, key: key, liked: liked, topicKey: self.topic.key)
                self.messages.append(message)
                self.messages.sortInPlace{$0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .OrderedDescending}

            }
            else{
                let liked = likedFd.value as! Bool
                let message = Message(message: messageDict, key: key, liked: liked, topicKey: self.topic.key)
                self.messages.append(message)
                self.messages.sortInPlace{$0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .OrderedDescending}
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
            }
            self.likedRef.keepSynced(true)
        }

        print(mesData.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: My take on this is that when you navigate away from a view controller it won't need to synchronize since it's not visible. If it *was* synchronizing when you're not looking at it, it would be leaky, and there's nothing worse than a leaky controller. To prevent leaks, implement ref.removeObserverWithHandle when moving away from a controller. This will cause it to stop observing and prevent leaks (and overhead). If an observer is then added, it will start observing and re-sync the data. In your case, if you don't clear the array, additional data will be added to the existing data.

Comment: Yeah but isn't it bad for user experience when he has to begin from top when he just went over to a new view and now the whole data is reloaded and the tableview started from top...

Comment: For example the user clicks on the cell and goes to the detail view controller then he goes back and all the data is gone and he has to scroll all the way to its original position again (with a huge amount of data for instance)

Comment: Ah. Well, yes, but no. In each view, add the observer when that view becomes active; When the user steps away from view A to view B, view A stops observing and view B starts. Then when the user goes back to view A, view B stops observing and view A picks it back up. That keeps the data fresh and prevents a lot of un-needed observing, stops leaks and helps battery drain.

Comment: Hm, but every observer will download the whole data new, that is not really good for the battery and of course not good for the memory...

Comment: Or how would you do it ? @Jay

Comment: When switching to a view, remove the current observer for the current view via ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle), clear the array, add the observer for the view being changed to (which will repopulate the array with cached data if available) and you are set. I think it's a good idea to avoid having 10 views all observing the same set of data, getting updates, trying to update the array etc - that would get tricky.

Comment: But the problem that the users position in the tableview gets lost is still not solved like this...

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Just keep track of which object (not index) in the tableview is currently selected and after (or while) the table view is repopulated, just reselect it. Don't use the index of the item as the positions may change as events occur. A simple way is to use a 'selectedKey' variable and as the table is repopulated and they key is read in, select it. As far as the position goes, you can use the same strategy. It also depends on how much data you are reading in, a thousands rows would probably be handled differently than 10 rows.

Comment: I have a variable for that but to find that object I have to enumerate through the array and that is too much when I have a huge amount of data...

Comment: I need to find a way where I can filter new objects and old ones, but firebase is not build for that as it seems...

Comment: No need to enumerate over an array. Store the key:value pairs in a dictionary (as object, firebaseKey) and use that to look up. Or .indexOf as in if let index = array.indexOf(theFirebaseKey) or even .find with if let index = find(array, theFirebaseKey)

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try it out tomorrow and tell you if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the first listener to a location, Firebase will download the current data for that location and start synchronizing the changes. It will keep a copy of the data available in memory.

If you add a second listener to the location, while the first one is still active, Firebase will not re-download the data. I just quickly verified this http://jsbin.com/foduxun/edit?js,console.

If you remove the first listener *before* you attach the second listener, Firebase will purge its cache. So then when you attach a listener again, it will re-download the data.

If you want to keep the data available on the device even after you detached all listeners, [enable disk persistence](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support):

```
[Firebase defaultConfig].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I have persistence enabled, my problem is that I have the data twice in my tableview and I don't want to clear my array every time the user switches the view, so I need to find a solution to check if the downloaded data is contained in my array...

Comment: But in firebase docs it is written that you should remove the listener in viewDidDisappear: and that firebase won't download the same data again...

Comment: Or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: I've described how it works. If the documentation says something different, provide a link (and we'll fix it ;-) )

Comment: It is actually a blog page https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-15-best-practices-uiviewcontroller-ios-firebase.html

Comment: How do I avoid that the same data gets loaded when I remove the handler after a segue and I go back to the view with a unwind segue ?